# Loading a 1bpp bitmap from byte array

Tags: c#, winapi, bitmap, handle

I have to load a 1bpp bitmap from a byte array to provide it to an external component. The component requires a handle to a bitmap.

I tried to load it to a `Bitmap` object and provide the result of `bitmap.GetHBitmap()`, but it looks like some weird conversion is done internally, and the resulting bitmap is not 1bpp anymore (when I provide the handle to the component, it complains about the bit depth).

When I load the bitmap from a file directly using Windows API function `LoadImage` it works fine, but I don't want to read them from a file since I already have the images in memory. Writing them to disk and reading them again is unnecessary I/O and would slow down my application too much.

How can I get a handle to a bitmap having its data in a byte array?

**Edit:**

I tried this code, but it shows me two different images. It should show identical images.

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)) * imageData.Length);
try
{
    Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, ptr, imageData.Length);
    handle = CreateBitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight, 1, 1, ptr);

    ShowImage(Image.FromHbitmap(handle));
    ShowImage(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageData)));
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```

Comment: What is "CreateBitmap" doing?

Comment: I read that I can use it to create a bitmap from a buffer. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183485(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Exactly what data format is your bytearray?  Is it the pixels of the bitmap image or is it the contents of the entire bitmap data.  There is a difference, a Bitmap will contain the pixel data along with some metadata, so in order to create the Bitmap object you will need to know what data the imageData contains.

Comment: The `imageData` array contains the data used to create a BMP file. If I call `File.WriteAllBytes(filename, imageData)`, I have a valid BMP file. I'm not sure if it's format  `CreateBitmap` function expects.